# F# Units of Measure ... Is there an example of TIME?

Tags: f#, time, units-of-measurement

Is TIME used in F# Units of Measure?

Answer (score 12):

there is a standard SI unit 'second' that you can use for representing time. You'll need to reference FSharp.PowerPack.dll and then you can use the following:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Math

let minute = 60<SI.s>
let twoMinutes = minute * 2
```

There are no built-in units for minutes/hours etc., because these are not standard units (and are actually only seconds multiplied by some number). However, you can define minutes too if you want:

```
[<Measure>]
type mins =
  static member of_seconds(sec) = sec / 60<SI.s> * 1<mins>

// converting seconds to minutes 
let timeInMinuts = mins.of_seconds(twoMinutes)
```

You can't use units with the standard System.DateTime type if that's you'r question, but you could create a wrapper that exposes the actual time (seconds/minutes) in the units you want:

```
open System

type DateTimeUnits(dt:DateTime) = 
  static member Now = new DateTimeUnits(DateTime.Now)
  member x.Second = dt.Second * 1<SI.s>
  member x.Minute = dt.Minute * 1<mins>
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that time can be in it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/andrewkennedy/archive/2008/08/29/units-of-measure-in-f-part-one-introducing-units.aspx

but, even it it isn't, you can write your own units.

This article from MS also may be useful, depending on which units you want.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243%28VS.100%29.aspx